# Plone - In an AutocompleteFieldWidget, how can I fix a glitch where (none) is still selected despite another selected?

Tags: plone

I have a form.Form whose interface has a field that is a AutocompleteFieldWidget.  `(none)` is displayed because the field is not required.  There is a glitch where `(none)` will remain selected even if the user hits another radio button.

```
Parent = schema.Choice(title=u'Parent Object',
                       source=ParentSourceVocabSourceBinder(),
                       required=False,
                       default=None)
```

The field is bound to an object class acting as a vocabulary.  The object has the required functions.  The search function searches for records of a mapped table based on the query from the textbox the user enters information into and the `__contains__`, `getTerm`, `getTermByToken` functions search for the matching record they require.

```
class ParentSourceVocab(object):
    implements(IQuerySource)
    vocabulary = SimpleVocabulary([])
    session = None

    def __contains__(self, term):
        """If term is None, set self.vocabulary equal to empty vocabulary and return none
        """
        """Else make fill the self.vocabulary with the found result and return SimpleTerm with result from running query
        """

    def getTerm(self, value):
        """If value is None, set self.vocabulary equal to empty vocabulary and return none
        """
        """Else make fill the self.vocabulary with the found result and return SimpleTerm with result from running query
        """
    def getTermByToken(self, token):
        """If token is None, set self.vocabulary equal to empty vocabulary and return none
        """
        """Else make fill the self.vocabulary with the found result and return SimpleTerm with result from running query
        """

    def search(self,query_string):
        if len(query_string) > 0:
            q_string = query_string.strip('"').strip("'")
            simples =[]              
            searchResults="""Query function"""
            for result in results:
                concat_string = """concatenated string for title"""
                simples.append(SimpleTerm(title=result.obj_name,value=obj_id,token=obj_id)
            self.vocabulary = SimpleVocabulary(simples)
            return simples
        else:
            self.vocabulary = SimpleVocabulary([])
            return None

class ParentSourceVocabSourceBinder(object):
    implements(IContextSourceBinder)

    def __call__(self, context):
        return ParentSourceVocab(context)
```

One thing I did notice is that if the user does click `(none)`, the form will recognize the `(none)` value was clicked, but if a value from the search results was clicked, it will remain clicked, despite it knowing `(none)` was selected.  Its almost as if the `(none)` and the search result radio buttons belong to two different "sets."

Am I misunderstanding how this widget works?  Or is there something wrong with my javascript?

Comment: Which version of Plone and z3c.form are you using? I remember this behavior on Plone 4.3.3 sites. The solution was to pin down z3c.form to 3.0.5.

Comment: I'm using Plone version 4.3.2 and the version of z3c.form I'm using was 3.0.2
I tried changing z3c.form to 3.0.5 in the buildout.  After running the buildout again, I'm still getting the same error where (none) acts as if its in a different set.

Do I need to upgrade Plone to 4.3.3?

Comment: ohh sry, the issue I mentioned was a "not required RadioWidget" issue, which leads into a problem. I need to investigate more. I faced your issue somewhere too, but I can't find it. stay tuned :-)

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey I found something interesting.  I added to my buildout collective.js.jqueryui (placed under the ZCML slugs section and the eggs section) and installed it through portal_quickinstaller.  In the JQueryUI utility that was added, there were several things that were checked, including "Autocomplete."   I unchecked Autocomplete and its working now.  I'm guessing the Autocomplete widget I'm using was conflicting perhaps with that script plugin that the JQueryUI lists?

Comment: Well, did you get any JS errors, if you enable the autocomplete widget? If so, you should write this as a solution/answer for this question. I guess others could have the same issue.  The problem I mentioned was one with Plone 4.3.3/z3c.form 3.0.5 + radiobuttons not Plone 4.3.2 + autocompletewidget.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried updating the version of z3c.form I was using.
And now I'm getting an ==NO VALUE== error.  I guess the template for the radio button (radio_input.pt) changed.

I was rebuilding my package and think I was causing a conflict with something else and  it seems the jQueryUI might have not been related at all.  I'm not sure yet because of being stuck with this.

Comment: I think I might have asked a question regarding that problem and my temporary solution was to change the radio_input template used to an earlier version copied into a templates folder I have via:
    widget = self.widgets["Parent"]
    widget.template = ViewPageTemplateFile("templates/radio_input.pt")  Anyhow, I'm not getting the same error I was having before now.

Comment: You ran into https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/issues/17 which in return is caused of zope.schema, where that NO_VALUE-construct is used, instead of `None`. And you solved it the same way I did in https://github.com/collective/Solgema.fullcalendar/issues/45 :-)

Comment: Refs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805675/plone-z3c-form-3-2-1-how-can-i-make-an-autocomplete-widget-that-is-not-a-requi

Comment: This is good for when you have access to the form class.  Currently I'm trying to use Solgema.fullcalendar and it seems to generate its own form for the content type, as opposed to calling the form class I have for it.  This is a problem because I can't use:
self.widgets["Parent"] widget.template = ViewPageTemplateFile("templates/radio_input.pt")  

since I don't have access to the form class.  Is there another way to set the template for the widget in my interface class, or should I try finding another widget to use instead of autocomplete?

Comment: I have some good news.   z3c.form version 3.2.9 released in February this year (2016) fixes the None issue.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.form/3.2.9#id13